# Local extrema for the function $f(x,y)= x^2+y^2 e^{x^2} + x\sin x$?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, optimization

I would like to find the stationary points if they exist and so I start by finding the partial derivatives for $x$ and $y$ and equal them to zero and from the second equation I know that $y=0$ but I can't find $x$? Am I and where am I making a mistake? Can someone explain me this type of mathematical task -- finding the extrema? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! It would help to code your questions with MathJaX to make them more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, if we have a local max/min, then the gradient is zero. Now, $y=0$ by inspection. Then, $D_{1}f(x,y) = 2x + y^2\cdot 2xe^{x^2}+\sin(x)+x\cos(x) \equiv 0$. Now, here $x=0$ is clearly a solution whenever $y=0$. Why? We have either an $x$ or $\sin(x)$ in each term and these functions are odd (or simply intersect the origin).

Now, for $x$ in a deleted neighbourhood (excluding 0) of $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, $D_{1}f(x,y) \neq 0$ (positive to the right and negative to the left of zero) and outside this region for $x>0$ we have $D_{1}f(x,y) > 2(\pi/2) + 0 - 1 - (\pi/2) > 0$. For $x<0$, the argument is similar but with an upper bound. Hence, the only extremum point is $(0,0)$. Also, by this argument we have shown it is a local min, since $D_{1}f(x,y) < 0$ for $x<0$ and $D_{1}f(x,y)>0$ for $x>0$. It is similar for $y$. There is no need to call on the 'second partial derivative test' - unless, of course, you really want to for practice.

Comment: Sorry, but did you miss the y^2 in the D1?(:..ok that's now littel better but yet I have tha answer that the (0,0) point is the min?

Comment: I wrote it with * mybe you didn't see it or thought it was a + .. anyway is than the solutions correct or the (0,0) is the min?

Comment: @banahova, see changes for $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2e^{x^2} + x\sin(x)$ above.

Comment: I think I got it.. Yes,mathematicians are also human :D.. so, I would do the second derivation and put them in the sqare matrix so I can analysis the determinant.. so I can conclude that thet point is the minimum,can I? But I am not sure I understand that the x=0 from the equotion?

Comment: Well... you know that $y=0$; these are coupled equations and so you can back substitute. This reduces to $2x + \sin(x) + x\cos(x) \equiv 0$. By inspection, $x=0$ is a solution. What is a root to both $x$ and $sin(x)$? However, as for the second derivative test, you'll see that it is inconclusive, but you can readily check that $f(x,y) \geq 0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Only 0? Because sin0=0 ?(:

Comment: Well... one argument is the one I gave above. In the neighbourhood $(0,\pi/2)$, we have $2x+\sin(x)+x\cos(x) > 2x + 0 - x = x > 0$. Similarly, in the neighbourhood $(-\pi/2,0)$, we have $2x+\sin(x)+x\cos(x) < 2x + 0 - x = x < 0$. Then proceed as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If you compute the partial derivative of your function with repect to y, you will see that it cancels only at y=0. For a cancellation of the partial derivative of your function with repect to x, it cancels at x=0 for y=0. Then (0,0) is a minimum point of the surface (what you could have guessed without derivatives).